# Webscraping for a specific text string issue

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, web

I am trying to webscrape definitions for Hebrew names in literature such as for these links. **https://www.biblestudytools.com/dictionaries/smiths-bible-dictionary/aaron.html**
https://www.biblestudytools.com/dictionaries/smiths-bible-dictionary/abednego.html

I have already scraped a list of names from another site that is currently in the list 'test'.

Here is what I have so far:

```
# create smiths dictionary
smiths_names = {}


# loop through the names in smiths dictionary 
try:    
    for name in test:
        # make a request to the website
        url = f"https://www.biblestudytools.com/dictionaries/smiths-bible-dictionary/{name}.html"
        page = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')


        # find the definition in the website, definitions are contained in <i> tags
        itags = soup.find('i')
        if itags:
            meaning = itags.get_text()
            smiths_names[name] = meaning
        else:
            print(f'{name} not found')

except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(e)
    print(f'{name} not found')
```

If I specify the text that I want e.g. for https://www.biblestudytools.com/dictionaries/smiths-bible-dictionary/aaron.html, I can scrape what I want ok, but I want to iterate through the list of names that I have in the 'test' list to get the definitions for each name. After I get the meaning of the name, both the name and the scraped meaning are added to a python dict as keys and values.

```
# find the definition in the website, definitions are contained in <i> tags
        itags = soup.find('i', text = 'a teacher, or lofty')
        if itags:
            meaning = itags.get_text()
            smiths_names[name] = meaning
```

I need to be able to get  the definitions from each of these dictionaries such as the entries that are in the links.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
soup.find_all('a')
# [<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
#  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a>,
#  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>]
```

to return all of the elements you looking for, as

```
soup.find(id="link3")
# <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>
```

returns just the first element that matches your target.
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Try using the following code instead:

```
# find all the <i> tags
    itags = soup.find_all('i')
    for i in itags:
        if name in i.text:
            meaning = i.text
            smiths_names[name] = meaning
            break
    else:
        print(f'{name} not found')
```